# Finding Process ID of my IE session for debugging in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer

Just switched over from eclipse to vs 2008 for debugging javascript, i feel more at home as i use vs 2008 for c# and when i come to "attach to process" i see 3 iexplorer processes and 2 of them with "script",

I only have 1 IE window open..

How can i identify which process ID i need to use? Anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using IE8 and it has the developer tools but i don't see anywhere i can identify the process ID...

Comment: You know that you can attach to more then one process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have your app open in the lone IE window you will see 2 IExplore processes.  One will have a window title, that will be the container and not the one you are interested in.  You will want to attach to the other process.

Of course this may be somewhat limiting if you also want other useful sites loaded and you prefer IE for that (I load sites like SO in FF but MSDN, at least in the past, worked better in IE).

A sysinternal tool that is useful here is [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) by watching what each iexplore process connects to you can determine which is the process you need.  Note that you need to do that with short time of doing any navigation, IE will drop idle connections after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and you'll see 2 processes (one nested in the tree which is your page). You're seeing 3 because you have more tabs open (IE8 uses one process per tab) so just close the other tab(s) and debug 1 page at a time.